# SQL Server : how to merge or group up rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In T-SQL, given input data such as

```
+------+------+--------+------+------+------+--------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 |  Col3  | Col4 | Col5 | Col6 |  Col7  | Col8 |
+------+------+--------+------+------+------+--------+------+
| 1    | 30   | 1.0000 | desc | NULL | NULL | NULL   | NULL |
| 31   | 60   | 2.0000 | desc | NULL | NULL | NULL   | NULL |
| 61   | 90   | 1.0000 | desc | NULL | NULL | NULL   | NULL |
| NULL | NULL | NULL   | NULL | 1    | 30   | 1.5000 | desc |
| NULL | NULL | NULL   | NULL | 1    | 30   | 2.5000 | desc |
| NULL | NULL | NULL   | NULL | 1    | 30   | 1.1000 | desc |
+------+------+--------+------+------+------+--------+------+
```

How can I obtain this output:

```
+------+------+--------+------+------+------+--------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 |  Col3  | Col4 | Col5 | Col6 |  Col7  | Col8 |
+------+------+--------+------+------+------+--------+------+
|    1 |   30 | 1.0000 | desc |    1 |   30 | 1.5000 | desc |
|   31 |   60 | 2.0000 | desc |    1 |   30 | 2.5000 | desc |
|   61 |   90 | 1.0000 | desc |    1 |   30 | 1.1000 | desc |
+------+------+--------+------+------+------+--------+------+
```

Rows 4, 5 and 6 from input "merge up" in order to get the desired output.

This should also work in case the total number of rows is not even.

Comment: How do you decide which rows to combine/pair?

Comment: What, in your data, denotes that the row where `Col1` has a value of `31` is related to the row where `Col7` has the value `2.5000`?

Comment: I guess I should have asked how to shift rows ?!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a solution. This doesn't work if the right half of the given table has more rows than the left. You can see what I'm doing and you can modify it to handle that case:

```
DECLARE @temp1 TABLE ( col1 INT, col2 INT, col3 DECIMAL(10,4), col4 NVARCHAR(20), col5 INT, col6 INT, col7 DECIMAL(10,4), col8 NVARCHAR(20) )

INSERT INTO @temp1 (col1,col2,col3,col4) VALUES
(1,30,1,'desc'),
(31,60,1,'desc'),
(61,90,1,'desc'),
(81,120,1,'desc')

INSERT INTO @temp1 (col5,col6,col7,col8) VALUES
(1,30,1.5,'desc'),
(1,30,2.5,'desc'),
(1,30,1.1,'desc')

SELECT col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8 FROM
(
    SELECT col1,col2,col3,col4,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY col5) AS RowNumber  FROM @temp1
    WHERE col1 IS NOT NULL
) t1 LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT col5,col6,col7,col8,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY col1) AS RowNumber  FROM @temp1
    WHERE col5 IS NOT NULL
) t2 ON t1.RowNumber = t2.RowNumber
```

Results:

[image: query results]

Comment: Thank you ! It works ! I cannot know which side has more records, meaning it might be a right join there at times, but that's some logic I will take care of otherwise.